# Un-ending image using mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Frog</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onscroll = infinity;
        function infinity () {
            document.write("<img src='frog.gif'>" + "<br/>");
        }
        while(window.onscroll){
            infinity();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src='earth.png'> 
    <br/>
    <img src='tiger.jpg'> 
    <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi guys, I want to know how would I loop the frog when every time I scroll down the frog image appears again thanks in advance!

Comment: It is very unclear what you're trying to achieve... And a ´br`tag is written ´<br />´

Comment: Hi bartdude, I'm trying achieve when use the side scroll bar down, the image (<img src='forg.gif'>) will appear again and again and thanks for the br tip.

Comment: Would using a repeating background be a possibility ?

Comment: Are the earth and tiger image big enough to that you get a scrollbar?

Comment: I'm curious, so I will ask.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: `document.write` replaces document content. Instead use a placeholder like DIV and append images as its children

Comment: @AaronDigulla - that's a tough question, right?  What's the display device?  An antique laptop?  An iPad?  A 1080p monitor in portrait orientation?  You pretty much can't assume a scrollbar exists.

Comment: Bartdude, yes that is one of the suggestion of my friends but sadly i don't really know how.

Comment: Surreal Dreams, it's an assignment and me and my classmates are stuck..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to add image when user actually turns mouse wheel (even when no actual scrolling is involved) - you need to capture "mousewheel" event. Universally crossbrowser you can to it like this:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
}
else {
    document.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);
}
```

If you create a placeholder to hold your future images:

```
<div id="fdiv">Froggies:</div>
```

You can add images to it on mousewheeling like this:

```
function MouseWheelHandler(e) {

    var e = window.event || e;
    var delta = e.wheelDelta

    if (delta < 0)

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "frog.gif";
    document.getElementById("fdiv").appendChild(img);

}
```

What this does is detects whether user scrolls mouse down (delta < 0) and if so - creates a new frog image and adds it to the DIV.

Here's demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8AxG/2/ place the mouse over window with words "Froggies:" and turn mouse wheel down.

Answer (score 1):

What you could try is to make a div modify its height when you scroll down (using Javascript). Then apply the image on the background and let it repeat using CSS:

```
div#infinity {
    background-image: url('frog.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

With other words, this script will add images when you scroll down:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST: Infinity Scroll</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var lastScrollTop = 0;
            $(window).scroll(function(event) {
                var st = $(this).scrollTop();
                if (st > lastScrollTop) {
                    $('div#infinity').append(
                        $('<div>').attr("id", "infinityimage")
                    );
                }
                else {
                    // upscroll code
                }
                lastScrollTop = st;
            });

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">

            html, body {
                height: 101%;
            }

            div#infinityimage {
                height: 190px;
                background-image: url('https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo6w.png');
                background-repeat: repeat-y;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="infinity">

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```